# Email module in python 3

Tags: python, email

So I'm following a tutorial to send email in python, the problem is that it was written for python 2 not python 3(which is what I have). So here's what I'm trying to get an answer what is the module for email in python 3? the specific module I'm trying to get is is:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMETex
```

I also have a feelling that when I get down to this module there will be an error (haven't got there yet because of
the module above giving error

```
import smtp
```

Here is the script:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMETex

fromaddr = ("XXXXX@mchsi.com")
toaddr = ("XXXX@mchsi.com")
msg = MIMEMultipart
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] =  toaddr
msg['Subject'] = ("test")

body = ("This is a test sending email through python")
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, ('plain')))

import smptlib
server = smptlib.SMPT('mail.mchsi.com, 456')
server.login("XXXXX@mchsi.com", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
text = msg.as_string()
sender.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
```

Comment: Those are located in `email.mime`: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/email.mime.html#module-email.mime

Comment: @doukremt yes that solved my problem but now getting this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\emailtest.py", line 9, in <module>
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @raspberry.pi You assigned `msg` to `MIMEMultipart`, which is the class. You forgot the parentheses: `msg = MIMEMultipart()`

Comment: now getting this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 318, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 289, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 417, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: how do i close this question u have answered it to an exstend that i have fiquered out how to solve it

Answer (score 12):

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
```

By the way here are some mistakes in your code:

```
fromaddr = "XXXXX@mchsi.com" # redundant parentheses
toaddr = "XXXX@mchsi.com" # redundant parentheses
msg = MIMEMultipart() # not redundant this time :)
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] =  toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "test" # redundant parentheses

body = "This is a test sending email through python" # redundant parentheses
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain')) # redundant parentheses

import smtplib # SMTP! NOT SMPT!!
server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.mchsi.com', 456) # `port` is an integer
server.login("XXXXX@mchsi.com", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") # on most SMTP servers you should remove domain name(`@mchsi.com`) here
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text) # it's not `sender`
```